# How To Assign TextField Value To Environment Object -- Error Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Binding<String>"

Tags: swiftui

I try to assign a text field value to a EnvironmentObject, but getting this error.
Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Binding"

```
import SwiftUI

class FilterSelections: ObservableObject {
    @Published var filters: [String: Any] = [
        "testFilter": "na"]
    @Published var fromDate: Date = Date()
    @Published var testNumber: String = ""
}


struct MainView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            
        ScrollView {
            VStack{
               NumberSearchSubView()
               Divider()
               EmptyView()
           }
         }
       }
    }
}


struct NumberSearchSubView: View {
    @State var searchByNumber: String = ""
    @EnvironmentObject var filters: FilterSelections
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment:.leading, spacing:10) {
            TextField("Enter your number", text: filters.testNumber).padding(10)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to use a `@Published` property as a Binding, you have to use the `$` symbol as a prefix:

```
TextField("Enter your number", text: $filters.testNumber)
```

This sends the projected value (ie the Binding) instead of just the `String` value.

Comment: Did this solve the issue for you? If so, please mark it as correct with the green checkmark.